# What is the terminology for adding an offset a variable in an arithmetic expression

Tags: terminology

I'm having an issue at work where several of us are seemingly arguing over a naming convention in piece of software we're writing.

Basically, suppose we have 3 variables $x, y, z$. $z$ is usually some nice even number like 1000. $x$ and $y$ are integers.

We want to compute a rounded version of $x + y$ (call it $a$) to the nearest multiple of $z$ by adding an offset to $y$.

Here's an example. $x = 1000, y = 200, z = 1000$.

$x + y = 1200$ and the nearest multiple is 1000. So the offset we need to add to $y$ is $-200$. The petty issue we're arguing over is whether we can call this operation of adding the offset to $y$ rounding? Is there an official mathematical terminology for this?

Comment: You can probably describe this with an appropriate scaling of the _nearest integer function_. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NearestIntegerFunction.html or the distance to the nearest integer https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Distance_to_Nearest_Integer_Function

Comment: In one of its ancient calculator manuals HP calls it _"normalize the data"_. This is an advice for big values with small differences in context of linear regression. See [manual of HP10C](https://literature.hpcalc.org/community/hp10c-oh-en-remake.pdf), note on p. 40.